# C# Side Scrolling on Touch Screen with JavaScript Site

Tags: c#, html, css, knockout.js

We have a C# Container, a Windows.Form.WebBrowser Class is the called, on a website that has no vertical scrolling (only horizontal).

Scrolling works great in Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox with the touch screen, however when the website is launched inside the Windows.Form.WebBrowser the touch scrolling does not work. It registers the touch/drag event like a left click and drag without grabbing the website.

It will also select the text on the website below.

We created a sample site to demonstrate the issue:

[Test website with side scroll. On a touch screen drag and scroll works](https://beta.slimcrm.com/sideScrollTest.html)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // webBrowser1
            // 
            this.webBrowser1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
            this.webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(2419, 1088);
            this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("https://beta.slimcrm.com/sideScrollTest.html", System.UriKind.Absolute);
            this.webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = false;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(16F, 31F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2419, 1088);
            this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
    }
}
```

We have 2 developers who have searched for 2 days through this site and the internet but nothing we try seems to allow the C# Windows.Form.WebBrowser to register the touch events and drag the website to the left.

We believe it has to be tied to the C#, because the drag events on the touch screen work great in all web browsers. Framework for the site is Knockout.js, Restful API, all within a C# Container.

Comment: I think you are probably out of luck.  Not sure if there are any native winforms controls that support touch events out of the box, windows will turn them into equivalent mouse events, so you won't be able to do anything with the touch screen that you can't do with a mouse.  The site running in native browsers will work fine as the browsers do support touch.

Comment: Thanks Ben, 

Pinch, zoom and other touch events seam to work just fine. THe only one that doesn't work is the drag. 

Do you still think there is no way to get a C# web container to allow side swipe on Windows 8.1?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, i suspect that the touch events are being turned into equivalent mouse and keyboard events and left click and drag is the "equivalent" mouse action.